# If limit of an integral of a positive integrand is 0, does that mean the limit of the integrand is 0?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, limits

I have 
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}} [h_n(x)-h(x)]^2dx =0
$$
I think this means
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} h_n(x)=h(x) 
$$
for almost all $x\in {\mathbb{R}}$? Am I correct? I am wondering because people fuss over interchange of limits and integrals.

Comment: How can you perform a definite integral and get $0$ as a result?

Comment: You mean I should write the bounds of integration?

Comment: You only get this along a subsequence.  Generally, convergence in $L^p$ implies converges pointwise almost everywhere along a subsequence.

Comment: But then for any $N$, there exists $n>N$ such that $h_n(x)$ differs from $h(x)$ for a region with length greater than 0. And the limit of the integral will not be 0? Please correct me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jonaz has pointed out, you can only guarantee convergence almost sure convergence along a subsequence.

The usual example of why this is true comes from the "typewriter" sequence of functions. Take the sequence of functions
\begin{align*}
f_0 &= \chi_{[0, 1]} \\
f_1 &= \chi_{[0, \frac{1}{2}]} \\
f_2 &= \chi_{[\frac{1}{2}, 1]} \\
f_3 &= \chi_{[0, \frac{1}{3}]} \\
f_4 &= \chi_{[\frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3}]} \\
f_5 &= \chi_{[\frac{2}{3}, 1]}
\end{align*}
and so on (hopefully it's clear how the sequence continues, if not please say). You can confirm that $f \to 0$ in $L^2$, but will not convergence almost surely since for any $x \in [0, 1]$, $f_n(x) = 1$ for infinitely many $n$.